# How do I disable the "Special keys" (Consumer Control Button) on a Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hid

My grandma's hands are very shaky and she keeps accidentally pressing one of the "special keys" along the top row of her laptop which are dual purpose with the function keys like unintentionally pressing F7 which turns off her track pad and causes the cursor to disappear.  Is there any way to disable the Consumer Control function of one of these keys?  Maybe edit the keyboard top level collection of the Human Interface Device (which I don't know where this would be located).

Any advice on key mapping is appreciated because I have no experience in this area.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your BIOS if you can switch the top row between F1, F2, .... and the special functions. I can do that in my BIOS (ThinkPad).

Answer (score 0):

You may have a dedicated fn lock key; mine looks like this (It can be toggled by pressing it simultaneously with Esc key):
[image: fn lock key]

You may also be able to toggle it in the bios. It looks like this in my bios:
[image: Bios fn lock]

Depending on the manufacturer, you may also be able to toggle it in a specific app, such as in My Asus Laptop, where I can do it in MyAsus App, which comes pre-installed, and I believe Dell and other manufacturers have similar features.

Answer (score 0):

A program is available for Windows (free) known as [KeyTweak](https://keytweak.en.softonic.com/). The description specifically references the ability to disable specific keys on the keyboard. The comments/reviews are fairly mixed. It appears half of the reviews suggest it works great and the other half not so great. There's one post that says it won't work with Windows 10, another says it works fine with Windows 10.

Another program which appears to have more positive reviews/comments is [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). This program also provides for other features, but does include the ability to disable specific keys. By using for search terms "disable specific keys windows 10," I found a reference to AutoHotKey, sort of a [mini-tutorial](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-a-key-on-the-keyboard-on-windows-10/). This linked site contains links to support documentation specific to disabling keys. It also notes that this is a software solution, allowing the disabled keys to work during boot and other non-windows "moments," such as LiveCD booting.